# Pandas: select what columns to add

Tags: python, pandas

Say that I have data that looks like:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'dontTouch1':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
                        'dontTouch2':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
                        'sumThis':   [1,1,3,5,8,13]})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'dontTouch1':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
                        'dontTouch2':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
                        'sumThis':   [1,1,3,5,8,13]})
```

Now, while:

```
sum_all = df1 + df2
sum_sumThis = df1['sumThis'] + df2['sumThis']
```

…returns the sum of *all* columns and only the `sumThis` columns, respectively, I am interested in something that creates a new DataFrame, where only `sumThis` is added together. Are there neat builtins for that?

I'm either missing something obvious, or will have to use cluttering slicing methodology otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something not quite "neat builtins", but also not quite "cluttering slicing methodology" (IMHO):

```
df3 = df1.copy()
df3.sumThis += df2.sumThis
>>> df3
    dontTouch1  dontTouch2  sumThis
0   0   0   2
1   1   1   2
2   2   2   6
3   3   3   10
4   4   4   16
5   5   5   26
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print pandas.DataFrame({'dontTouch1': df1['dontTouch1'], 
                        'dontTouch2': df1['dontTouch2'], 
                        'sum': df1['sumThis'] + df2['sumThis'] })
   dontTouch1  dontTouch2  sum
0           0           0    2
1           1           1    2
2           2           2    6
3           3           3   10
4           4           4   16
5           5           5   26
```